# Can you automatically cast an object of one class to a subclass and call an overloaded method in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, factory-pattern

I have the following setup:

```
class Base {};
class ImplA extends Base {};
class ImplB extends Base {};
class ImplC extends Base {};

Base baseFactory(int type) {
    switch(type) {
    case 0:
        return new ImplA();
    case 1:
        return new ImplB();
    case 2:
        return new ImplC();
}

Base a = baseFactory(0);
Base b = baseFactory(1);
Base c = baseFactory(2);


List<Base> list = new ArrayList<Base>();

list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);

// Somewhere else I have:
interface BaseHandler {
    process(ImplA a);
    process(ImplB b);
    process(ImplC c);
};
```

Now, what I would like to be able to do is something along the lines of:

```
class Processor {

BaseHandler bh;

Processor(BaseHandler bh) {
    this.bh = b;
}

void processList(List<Base> list) {

    for (Base x : list) {
        bh.process(x);
    }
}
```

And then have a user implement BaseHandler and be able to construct a Processor to operate on each element in the Base list.

But, this does not work as `process(Base)` is not defined.  It may seem simple to just add 3 if statements, but I already have a switch like structure in building instances of classes extending the Base.  It seems unnecessary to repeat this over and over.  Is there a way to achieve this idea without writing an intermediate step that determines the runtime class of each Base in the list and calls the appropriate method (in effect another switch case -- but it would be if's)?

I think one work around idea would be to make each Base have an abstract `process` method which needs to be implemented by the Impl classes.  However, this is not acceptable in my situation since the user will not be implementing the Impl classes.  Basically, I need `process` to be a user-defined callback.  Further, it does not make sense for `process` to be a member of the Impl or Base classes since it is in no way related.  It's a separate callback that needs to respond dynamically to the type it is called with.  And the type is always guaranteed to be a subclass of Base.

Comment: Nope.  You've listed all the possibilities.  Remember, overload resolution is always done at _compile time._  If you want to call a specific overload, you have to know at compile time that the object has that class.  (Explicitly testing and casting suffices, of course, to prove the object's type to the compiler.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need the "intermediate step" that you describe, but it need not be `if` statements. What you're looking for is double dispatch using the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Basically your `Base` class would have a method:

```
void accept(BaseHandler handler);
```

and each subclass would implement it as:

```
handler.process(this);
```

where `this` would resolve to the correct type in each subclass at compile-time.

Comment: "I think one work around idea would be to make each Base have an abstract process method which needs to be implemented by the Impl classes. However, this is not acceptable in my situation since the user will not be implementing the Impl classes."  How does that not rule out this answer?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: In that case, the actual processing logic would reside in the Impl classes. Double dispatch, on the other hand, is merely a way of routing the call to the correct handler; the logic is still in the `BaseHandler` implementation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman This is actually a perfect solution as it doesn't require the user to implement each of the Impl classes.  What I was ruling out was the user having to implement the Impl classes.  This gives the user the ability to define custom code that is dynamically called for each type while at the same time clustering all of that logic in one place.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the Visitor pattern.  You put an abstract method on `Base`, but all it does is call the appropriate method in `BaseHandler`:

```
public interface Base {
    void acceptHandler(BaseHandler handler);
}
```

Then your concrete implementations override `acceptHandler` and call the correct overload.

```
public class ImplA implements Base {
    public void acceptHandler(BaseHandler handler) {
        handler.process(this);
    }
}
```

At this point there's not much value in the overloading, and you'd be better off just giving your methods descriptive names.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is the **Visitor** pattern here:

```
public interface BaseVisitor {
  void caseA(ImplA a);
  void caseB(ImplB b);
  void caseC(ImplC c);
}

public class MyVisitor implements BaseVisitor {
  void visit(List<Base> bases) {
    for (Base b : bases) {
      b.accept(this);
    }
  }
  public void caseA(ImplA a) { // ... }
  public void caseB(ImplB b) { // ... }
  public void caseC(ImplC c) { // ... }
}

public abstract class Base {
  abstract void accept(BaseVisitor visitor);
}

public class ImplA {
  public void accept(BaseVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.caseA(this);
  }
}
public class ImplB {
  public void accept(BaseVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.caseB(this);
  }
}
public class ImplC {
  public void accept(BaseVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.caseC(this);
  }
}
```